# SilverStripe Fluent issue for Turkish language

Tags: php, silverstripe

For a website that runs in 5 languages (translation by Fluent mod) there seems to be an issue for the **Turkish** language only. When switching to language in back-end to Turkish, this error is thrown:

`PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'CurrentPageIdentifier' not found in /home/<..path to project>/cms/code/controllers/CMSMain.php on line 12`

It appears to only affect the Turkish language, all other languages seem to work fine. I've tried to manually delete all columns with tr_TR appendix and re-run dev/build?flush, didn't solve it.

**Fluent.yml config**

```
---
Name: myfluentconfig
After: '#fluentconfig'
---
Fluent:
  default_locale: en_US
  locales:
    - en_US
    - pl_PL
    - de_DE
    - nl_NL
    - tr_TR
  aliases:
    en_US: en
    pl_PL: pl
    de_DE: de
    nl_NL: nl
    tr_TR: tr

---
Name: myfluenti18nconfig
After: '#fluenti18nconfig'
---
i18n:
  default_locale: en_US
```

Comment: Do you also have a backtrace of this error (you'll get it when you install the xdebug extension on your dev server)? Then you can see what code makes that error appear in the CMSMain class. What versions of SilverStripe and Fluent are you using? Did you flush?

Comment: What could cause this? Even you did manually delete tables, can you exclude the Content in the DB as cause of the problem? Does it also happen on an empty DB after dev/build? ... the other thing you could try to exclude are the lang-files yml & php on all modules and as usual, don't forget to flush :)

Comment: @wmk unfortunately it's not possible to install xdebug. I just installed a fresh copy of SS (on server) and installed fluent module with the same configuration. Same exact issue. I did the same test on my local server, no issues.

Comment: so you need to find the differences between your local server and the live server... In an ideal world it's the same OS, same webserver and php version, same php modules, locales etc... installed. (plus stuff for debugging).